# SQLite data fetching problem after row Delete?

Tags: android, sqlite

friends,

i am trying to delete row and then when i try to fetch all records from database
i get exception any one guide me what mistake am i doing?

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "example.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";

   private Context context;
   private SQLiteDatabase db;

 public dbHelper(Context context) {
      this.context = context;
      OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
      this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
      this.insertStmt = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);
   }


    public List<String> selectAll() {
          List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
          Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "name" }, 
            null, null, null, null, "name desc");
          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             do {
                list.add(cursor.getString(0));
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
          }
          if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
             cursor.close();
          }
          return list;
       }

       public int DeleteName(String name)
       {
           int rowsEffected = this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME,"name=?", new String[] {name});
           this.db.close();
           return rowsEffected;
       }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Comment: What sort of exception do you have? Do you use 1 thread for delete and get methods?

Comment: yes same thread...using same object to call delete function then selectAll....i guess that is the problem do i need to take new reference after deleting a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you opened db before call selectAll()?
You closed it in delete method.

Anyway it is good practice to open db before work with it and close it after the work is done.